# How to correctly do relative imports with nested packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

Yes I read the answer to this [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time). No I did not find it really useful as I tried both solutions and it did not work for me. See below.

I have the below folder structure.

(I do not have any `__init__.py`, as I understood they're not required anymore. I have Python 3.7)

```
project
├── subpackage1
└── subpackage2
    ├── launch
    |   └── launchFunc.py
    |   └── launchFunc.sh
    └── src
        └── somemodule.py
```

launchFunc.py:

```
from somemodule import func

func()
```

launchFunc.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m launch.launchFunc
```

Then I open command line and I cd into `project/subpackage2/` and I run the below command:

`./launch/launchFunc.sh`

and I get the below error:

```
from somemodule import func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'somemodule'
```

If I replace `from somemodule import func` with `from ..src.somemodule import func`, I get:

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

What is the correct way to import and/or run scripts in python ?
Isn't there a way to have all functions automatically imported to all required modules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found out that by:

- always using the full path to import: `import func from subpackage2.somemodule`
- always running things from the `project` folder
  it will work fine.

I think this is a rule I should adopt for all my projects.